# How do I use environment variables in an Eclipse .classpath file?

Tags: eclipse, ant, classpath, environment-variables

In Windows I have an environment variable EXTERNAL_LIB_ROOT that points to C:\Program Files\MyExternalLibRoot. On another machine, it may point to C:\ExternalLibs.

In an ant build.xml file I would use:

```
<pathelement location="${env.EXTERNAL_LIB_ROOT}/path/to/jar.jar"/>
```

How do I set up an Eclipse project .classpath file to use the EXTERNAL_LIB_ROOT environment variable? Is it possible to have Eclipse auto generate the build.xml file using the environment variable as above?

Answer (score 4):

Not an environment variable, but you can set up a [Path Variable](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cpathvars.htm) in Eclipse. Path variables are per-workspace. They are therefore a convenient way of sharing a common location among multiple projects within a workspace. I have used them to share a lib folder among projects.

To create a Path Variable (either for the first time, or to re-use an existing one in a project):

- File / New / Folder

  - Opens the New Folder dialog
- Click on the Advanced button
- Select the "Link to folder in the file system" check box
- Click the Variables button

  - Opens the Select Path Variable dialog
- Select or create a Path Variable

In your case, create a variable called EXTERNAL_LIB_ROOT.

(BTW, rather than generating a build.xml from your .classpath, I would suggest instead creating .classpath and .project from your build.xml.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Ant addon [**Ant4Eclipse**](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) will help you, see
 http://www.ant4eclipse.org/userguide-jdt and [jdtClassPathVariable](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/node/53)